# CallBack URL for payment gateway redirecting to homepage instead of executing callback function

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, urls, wp-api, callbacks

I am working on a payment plugin for Woocommerce which requires that I set the URL to redirect after payment. I set this as   home_url('/?').'wc-api=WC_Payment_Gateway'.

The payment gateway appends transaction to the redirect URL like this http://localhost:8000/?wc-api=WC_Payment_Gateway/?ref=TES000002271020677808 which makes the URL invalid. I need to do this in order to trigger the function to verify the payment

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the payment provider then. You can either ask them to fix their redirection to URLs that already have query strings, or you'll have to add an extra route to WordPress so that you can create a redirect endpoint without a ?.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please can you guide me on how to add an extra route to WordPress so that I can create a redirect endpoint?

Comment: Sorry, I've never done that myself. I'd guess you want [add_rewrite_endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) or [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).